# Fracture part of the object

Tags: cycles-render-engine, add-on

How would one fracture only part of the object with cell fracture add-on?
I have this object:

[image]

Can I only fracture center of the object, so that the top and the bottom are **completely** unfractured? I can't just make constraints since the object is glass in cycles and unwanted fractures are clearly seen... I tried using cursor close, I tried fracturing with child object, but regardless of what I do, I can't get only the center to fracture...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do this with a slight work-around.

1. In Edit mode select the top half of the object

   [image]
2. Separate it from the bottom using , P -> Selection
3. In Object mode select the object you wish to fracture and run the cell fracture command

[image]

4. If you want to you can join them back together afterwards with Ctrl J

Comment: i wanted to perform fracturing only on the center of the object, but this workaround is a great way to go. thanks a lot!